# Getting return value from dynamic sql from stored procedure (SQL Server and C# ADO.NET)?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, ado.net, sp-executesql

I created a stored procedure to get return value from a dynamic sql. I get the following exception:

> String[1]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0.

My proc:

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[Review_Get_PrePopValue](@sqlQuery nvarchar(500), @display nvarchar(200) OUTPUT)
as

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlQuery,   
    @display OUTPUT
```

My Code:

```
public string GetAnswerValue(string contentSQL, string parameter, string parameterValue)
{
    string sqlstatement = contentSQL.Replace(parameter, parameterValue);

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        string prePopValue;
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
        comm.Connection = conn;
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        comm.CommandText = "Review_Get_PrePopValue";

        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sqlQuery", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = sqlstatement; 
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
        {
            Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
            ParameterName = "@display",
            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar
        });

        conn.Open();
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

        prePopValue = comm.Parameters["@display"].Value.ToString();
        return prePopValue;
    }
}
```

My sql string:

```
Select @display = Grant_Number From GMIS_Grants where grant_id=1
```

Comment: That's a very interesting SQL injection path you've made there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direction = ParameterDirection.Output, ParameterName = "@display", Size = 200, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar

Needed to set the size for nvarchar

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN

For bidirectional and output parameters, and return values, you must set the value of Size.

Also, add this at the end of your SP.

```
SELECT @display;
```

Comment: What did u mean, Is this wrong: "@display nvarchar(200) OUTPUT"?

Comment: I'm talking about the .NET code. See that you're not specifying the Value of second parameter. You should send something there, even if an empty string, just like the first param.

Comment: Its @display is an output, how do I assign it a value? and why?

Comment: got it,    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
                    ParameterName = "@display",
                    Size = 200,
                    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar

Comment: Needed to set the size for nvarchar